# jQuery, count number of elements and then apply number of another jQuery function

Tags: jquery

I'm currently using this little snippet to first count the number of `.item-wrap` elements and then apply this number to a function that fades out a button after x number of clicks;

```
var count_elements = $('.showcase-grid .item-wrap').length;

var countclick = 0;

$("#load-items").on("click", function() {
    countclick = countclick + 1;
    if (countclick >= count_elements) {$("#load-items").fadeOut(3000); } 
});
```

But, for whatever reason, it doesn't seem to work. If I replace `count_elements` with a static number then the function works as intended so I assume I'm doing something wrong in my initial variable?

One thing I should add, the `.items-wrap` elements are themselves created via jQuery in a "slice" function. The code for which is here;

```
var divs = $(".showcase-grid > .item");
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i+=3) {
  divs.slice(i, i+3).wrapAll("<div class='item-wrap row hide'></div>");
}
```

Could that be the cause of my woes?

Comment: When, in relation to the page loading, is the code to create the elements called? Is it a one time thing when the page loads, or is it in reaction to an event?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist it's just a one time thing on page load.

Comment: try to replace `countclick >= count_elements` with `countclick >= $('.showcase-grid .item-wrap').length`

Comment: In that case, call the code that does `var count_elements = $('.showcase-grid .item-wrap').length;` **after** the code to add the elements, and it will have the correct length. jQuery objects and such don't automatically update, but there's still only a need to call it *once*.

Comment: @ArunPJohny that seemed to do the trick. Thank you! Not sure why the variable wouldn't work though...

Comment: @DeanElliott because when the variable is defined the `.showcase-grid .item-wrap` elements are not loaded

Answer (score 0):

If your `.item-wrap` elements aren't loaded into the DOM when you try and count them you will get an error, try wrapping your initialisation in a `document.ready` like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var count_elements = $('.showcase-grid .item-wrap').length;
]);
```

#### Edit:

You may also want to try `document.load` like so:

```
$(document).load(function() {
    var count_elements = $('.showcase-grid .item-wrap').length;
]);
```

Comment: Everything is wrapped in a `document.ready` already, and also a `document.load` too and neither seemed to work